# Expect Script to match on multi-line response

Tags: regex, expect

I am receiving the response to a Unix cat /etc/hosts and would like to match on this data with Expect - so I can write it local disk.

I have

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn nc -lvnp 9090
match_max 100000
expect -re {.*(Connection received).*}

puts "Getting hosts file"

send -- "cat /etc/hosts\r"
expect -re "(.*)\n"
```

The host file is multiple lines and I am unable to construct the correct regular expression to match on it.

Help would be gratefully received

Update

When interact with when the remote service via netcat manually the response interaction looks like this :

```
nc -lvnp 9090 Listening on 0.0.0.0 9090 Connection received on
192.168.236.135 44686 cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

my Expect code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn nc -lvnp 9090
match_max 100000
expect -re {.*(Connection received).*}

puts "******Getting hosts file*******"
log_user 0
send -- "cat /etc/hosts \r"

expect -re "(.*\[\r\n])+"

#expect -re "(.*\[\r|\n]).*"
#expect -re "(.*\[\t|\r|\n]).*"
expect -re "(.*\[\r\n]).*$"

puts "Output 0 string"
puts <<<<$expect_out(0,string)>>>>
puts ""
puts "Output 1 string"
puts <<<<$expect_out(1,string)>>>>
puts ""
puts "Output buffer"
puts <<<<$expect_out(buffer)>>>>
puts ""

puts [open  hosts.txt w] $expect_out(buffer)

send -- "\x03"
```

Just seem to be unable to match on the whole response - I'm not 100% sure if I need to match on EOF or EOL or something else. The newlines and tab are also part of the problem I think.

I basically just to to capture the whole response from the 'send -- "cat /etc/hosts" and write that to disk

Answer (score 0):

turns out he response from the remote server was too quick.

A simple 'sleep 1' was good enough to slow things down

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn nc -lvnp 9090
match_max 100000
expect -re {.*(Connection received).*}

puts "Getting hosts file"

send -- "cat /etc/hosts\r"
sleep 1
expect -re "(.*)\n"
```